# Stop Quicksilver Clipboard History From Popping Up On OSX

Tags: macos, quicksilver

Quicksilver and the clipboard history feature in particular are invaluable tools for me, but the clipboard history has the infuriating habit of opening up randomly and sitting on my screen until I dismiss it using the same hotkey I use to open it.

Has anyone found a fix that makes the clipboard history only show up when summoned?

Answer (score 0):

This would best be handled as a bug for the developer as there isn't anything as a *user* that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Drag it to the side of the screen. It'll disappear into the edge. Mouse over to the edge and it'll pop up again. The hotkey will work as normal. This stops the random pop-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you use spaces this workaround does not workaround.

For best results, go here and add your voice with a bug report:

https://github.com/tiennou/blacktree-alchemy/issuesearch?state=open&q=clipboard#issue/45